# SQL changing select from column orientation to row

Tags: sql

I have a simple query,

```
select a.*,b.* from myTableA a join myTableB b on a.ID = B.ID
```

and this works fine.  However, it displays as

`ID|Value|Fruit|ID1|Value1|Fruit1`

How do I get the results to do

`ID|Value|Fruit`
`1|A|Apple`
`1|B|Mango`

Comment: Just to be clear, `Value` will always be `A` if it comes from `myTableA` and `B` if it comes from `myTableB` - is that correct?

Comment: Umm all I really want to do is stop duplicating columns and put A and B in it's own rows

Comment: You should read up on normalisation. Your datamodel is not very efficient

Comment: @Mike Yes, but is it true that the values in the `Value` column will **always be** `A` if they are in the `myTableA` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a `UNION` query you are describing:

```
SELECT ID, Value, Fruit
FROM myTableA
WHERE ID IN (SELECT B.ID FROM myTableB B)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Value, Fruit
FROM myTableB
WHERE ID IN (SELECT A.ID FROM myTableA A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* from myTableA a join myTableB b on a.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.ID,
a.Value,
a.Fruit
from myTableA a join myTableB b on a.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

unselect b like this

```
SELECT a.* from myTableA a left join myTableB b on a.ID=b.ID
```